# Azure Web App Easy Auth handling (/.auth/me)

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-web-app-service

We are using Azure Web App Easy Auth, and use the Web App as a reverse proxy which forwards traffic to an angular app.

The angular app uses /.auth/me and uses the token and pass it to a REST API. However, if user is idle for a long time, seems that the /.auth/me session times out and we can't get it anymore.

However, the web app doesn't redirect anymore to the MS Login page (as it does when we enter the URL at first time).

Is there a proper way to handle it?

Thank you

**Edit**:

For example, we are calling this using httpGet in Angular

https://myreverseproxy-dev-asse-web-d.azurewebsites.net/.auth/me

This returns JSON with the auth token.

But after a few hours that user is idle, seem it returns blank []. Probably because the session is timed out or the authentication for this endpoint has a timeout.

Comment: Provide what code you have tried, got any error message or any performance issue while redirecting to MS Login Page so that the community would assist better!

Comment: Added more details

Answer (score 0):

You have to give the redirect URL by registering your Azure Web App in App Registrations Service:

[image]

If it is already registered in App Registrations, then your app service from Azure Portal > Type "App Registrations" in Main search > Select your registered App Service > Select "Authentication" Where you configure the redirect URI:
[image]

Refer to this MS [Doc1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reply-url) for Redirect URI Limits & restrictions and [Doc2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-web-app-sign-user-app-configuration?tabs=aspnetcore) for configuring the `CallbackPath`, `SignedOutCallbackPath` in the code like `appsettngs.json` if the language is ASP .NET Core, `web.config` for ASP .NET, `application.properties` for Java, etc.